# VBA: Error 13, type mismatch

Tags: vba, runtime-error

I want to let Excel automatically change the color of a cell if that cell's value is either larger or smaller by 10% than the cell that at same row but three columns to the left.

Here is the code:

```
Sub testing1()
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer

    For x = 35 To 5 Step -3
        For y = 11 To 75 Step 1
            If Cells(y, x).Value < 0.9 * Cells(y, x - 3).Value Or _
               Cells(y, x).Value > 1.1 * Cells(y, x - 3) Then
                Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Before I defined `y`, I used a single row, like 11. It is like this: `cells(11,x).value`; the code ran without problems.

However, when I change from numbers to variable `y`, I get an error: `Error 13, type mismatch`.

What is the source of this error?

Comment: You should format your code as such. There is an orange ? that you can click when editing to see how.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use Conditional Formatting and not worry about coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put one more condition layer. Actually if you have a cell with `a` in it and you multiply it by 5 , you usually get a type mismatch error.

```
If IsNumeric(Cells(y, x)) Then
    If Cells(y, x).Value < 0.9 * Cells(y, x - 3).Value Or Cells(y, x).Value > 1.1 * Cells(y, x - 3) Then

        Cells(y, x).Interior.ColorIndex = 22

    End If
End If
```

Comment: I found my data contains "#Div/0!", that caused the issue. I did the code you suggested, it works! Thank you very much.